# Replace the selected pixel

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, action

How do I replace the selected pixel of the image? I used set pixel and get pixel concept but not getting the desired effect. 
                                                                                  http://www.digital-photography-school.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/07/before-after.jpg

```
var s_color = 0x0083C7;
color_picker.addEventListener(ColorPickerEvent.CHANGE, changeColor);
function changeColor(ColorPickerEvent)
{
var _color = color_picker.selectedColor.toString(16);
var color = String("0x"+_color);

for (var j = 0; j <m_inputImage.width; j++)
{
    for (var k = 0; k < m_inputImage.height; k++)
    {

        if (m_inputImage.getPixel(j,k)== s_color)
        {
            m_inputImage.setPixel(j,k,color);
        }

    }
}
s_color = color;
}
```

I want similar type effect.
Please guide me.

Comment: We need more information, for example your code. It's very hard to help you when all we can do is guess at your problem.

Comment: http://www.digital-photography-school.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/07/before-after.jpg                                       i want this type Effect.

Comment: Sumit, your code please... We are not telepaths here...

Comment: is m_inputImage a BitmapData object?

Comment: changeColor(ColorPickerEvent) should be changeColor(event:ColorPickerEvent)

Answer (score 1):

This is not a job for BitmapData, you should use Pixelbender for this.
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/pixel_bender_basics.html

You can find all shaders here, there are a lot of hue/saturation and color manipulation filters so pick one that suits you the best.
http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/exchange/index.cfm?event=productHome&exc=26&loc=en_us

Comment: BTW, there's no correctly satisfying shader in that library, I needed the same effect, and compiled a shader myself via Pixel Bender.

Comment: Pixel Bender is definitely the route to go here. Pixel Bender was created specifically for image manipulation and is quite good (and quite efficient) at it.

Comment: PixelBender definitely best choice if available - but it doesnt work on mobile

Answer (score 0):

I would use Photoshop instead of Flash to achieve the effect you desire.

However Photoshop is kind of expensive, so I would use the [Bitmap](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Bitmap.html) class in conjunction with the [BitmapData](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html) class and use an algorithm to run through each pixel and check for a certain threshold of red and convert it to the right threshold of yellow. If you would post the code you already have written I could possibly add to it, I'm not going to spend the next hour writing an example though.

Comment: I think if he wanted to manipulate images in a static way, he'd use photoshop already instead of asking how do to it in code.